# Self-coupling of gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, interactions

From the EInstein eqn it is obvious the metric field couples to itself since $R_{\mu\nu}$ is derivative and multiplication of $\Gamma$'s.

Some GR textbooks explained this coupling as necessary from the point of view of the equivalence principle. For example, two particles are bound by gravity, their gravitational energy will be less; hence inertial mass will be larger than gravitational mass. But I am confused about how self-interaction of gravity solves the issue. Any comment or reference is appreciated.